# Installing Azure SDK on Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2010

I am currently setting up a development VPC to test some new technology. I have installed VS 2010 Beta 2.

I now want to install the Azure development tools. The latest download that I have been able to find is the July CTP. This is suposed to work with Beta 1.

I get the following error message:

- Visual Studio 2008 is currently installed but this product requires Service Pack 1. Please install SP1 and try again.
- Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 requires the Visual Web Developer feature to be installed in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (Standard or above).

Am I missing something or is it not possible to install it on Beta 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Windows Azure Tools only supports VS 2010 Beta 1. I expect a new version with support for Beta 2 pretty soon though (at least when the PDC comes around.)

Comment: Thanks, found this link http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/10/18/windows-azure-tools-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx